# How to use Bundler & Minifier tool in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, visual-studio-extensions

Recently, I use ASP.NET Core to develop my project. I have a question like that: there is many `css` and `js` file I want refer in my View page, so If it is exist a tool that can combine some css or js to one. It is like following

```
<link href="~/Content/css/a1.css" rel="stylesheet" asp-append-version="true" />
<link href="~/Content/css/a2.css" rel="stylesheet" asp-append-version="true" />
```

I want to te result is that:

```
<link href="~/bundles/css/a.min.css" rel="stylesheet" asp-append-version="true" />
```

Then I search it on Google, I got the tool `Bundler& Minifier`, an extension in Visual Studio. I want to know how to write the bundleconfig.json file in my project? and how to use it to combine the css or js file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are number of ways you can use Bundler & Minifier in asp.net core project. Most common is using **BundlerMinifier.Core** tool

To use BundlerMinifier.Core tool, simply add a reference to BundlerMinifier.Core within the tools section of your existing project.json file as seen below :

```
"tools": {
  "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
}
```

After adding the tool, you'll need to add a bundleconfig.json file in your project that will be used to configure the files that you wish to include within your bundles. A minimal configuration can be seen below :

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/site.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/css/site.css"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/site.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/site.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    "sourceMap": false
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/semantic.validation.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/semantic.validation.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    }
  }
]
```

After your bundles have been configured, you can bundle and minify your existing files via the following command :

```
dotnet bundle
```

There is also a [Bundler & Minifier extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier) available for Visual Studio which will help you to bundle and minify your files.

Comment: should i use  `"scripts": {
    "precompile": [ "dotnet bundle" ]
  },` in my project.json ?

Comment: Yes, you can. This way you can automate Bundling and Minification process as a part of build.

Comment: I use the way in my project that you said, it build and run successfully. Thank you for answering.