# Minify AngularJS service generated by ASP.NET Boilerplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using the template for ASP.NET MVC5, with AngularJS v1.4.8 and ABP v2.1.2.0. I'm preparing my web app to deploy to production and I need to bundle and minify the JS files. I use WebEssencial to do it. But I noticed that JS files (AngularJS services) generated for ABP aren't minified.

Is there a way to minify the AngularJS services generated by ABP for the application services?

Thanks a lot. I appreciate your help.

EDIT

Those JS files are automatically generate by ABP https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dynamic-Web-API

Comment: because they are being created on the fly. so minifiers cannot catch it

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Bundle & Minifier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier), it’s the best and easy tool for asp.net core projects.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41517843/6527049) is the detailed information on how to use it.

Microsoft also has provided a well explained documentation for [Bundling and Minification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification).

You have to change bundleconfig.json file according to your requirement.

Run `dotnet bundle` from command prompt once done with the configuration.

Comment: The OP is talking about dynamic js created at runtime. He's already using a minify tool (web essentials).